# XSLT 1.0: How to avoid ascii conversion?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

In a XML file I have some tags like this:

```
<foo>this is a &quot;test&quot;</foo>
```

When I process it with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
```

I get as output: `this is a "test"`.

What I would like to get back is the text (as it is)

```
this is a &quot;test&quot;
```

without any sort of conversion/processing.

How can I ask to XSLT 1.0 to avoid any sort of "processing"?

I tried:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes|no" />
```

but it doesn't work.

In case there is a solution, it is possible to have it as "default" for all the `<xsl:value-of />` inside the XSLT file?

Comment: What type of output are you producing? `<xsl:output method="text"/>`?

Comment: the same, like nothing has changed.

Comment: that was not exactly an answer to my question...

Comment: @Randomize What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: The reason disable-output-escaping doesn't work is because it does exactly the opposite. You want to enable escaping in places where it isn't happening.

Comment: What is your real requirement? WHY do you want to do this, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am converting a xml to csv file. It convert &quot; to " in the single cell, which of course is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the XML `<foo>this is a &quot;test&quot;</foo>` then any XML parser any XSLT processor uses parses the entity references `&quot;` into Unicode characters `"` and the XSLT processor will work with a `foo` element node having a text child node with the string value `this is a "test"`, meaning the XSLT processor will not have any knowledge whether your original XML had a Unicode character `"` or an entity reference `&quot;`.

So there is no way to preserve the entity reference (unless you preprocess the XML and convert entity references into markup the XSLT can distinguish, see http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ for an option in the world of Java).

With XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 you could use a character map https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps to map any quote character in the result to an entity reference. That would however not preserve the entity references from the input, instead it then outputs any quote character as a character reference. See http://xsltransform.net/bwdwrK which does

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output use-character-maps="escape"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="escape">
        <xsl:output-character character='"' string="&amp;quot;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

and transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>This is a &quot;test&quot;.</foo>
    <foo>This is another "test".</foo>
</root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <foo>This is a &quot;test&quot;.</foo>
    <foo>This is another &quot;test&quot;.</foo>
</root>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can use only XSLT 1.0

Comment: alternatively can I just replace &quot; with a single quote ' ?